# How byte[] values are converted to e.g struct?

Tags: c#, arrays

How `1, 5` makes `1281` here?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Rect
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte left;
    [FieldOffset(1)] public short top;
}

public static T ByteArrayToInstance<T>(byte[] bytes)
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        var stuff = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
        return stuff;
    }
    finally
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var bytes = new byte[] { 10 /* fits whole byte / field 0*/, 1, 5 };
    var result = ByteArrayToInstance<Rect>(bytes);

    Console.WriteLine(result.left);
    Console.WriteLine(result.top);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1281 = 256 x 5 + 1

So the 1 and 5 are fed to the low and high byte of the short respectively. Little-endian system.